# git branch -d <BRANCH>: Fatal - Couldn't look up commit object for HEAD

Tags: git

Say I am in a bare repository (a remote), if I try to delete a branch with `git branch -d <branch_name>` I get the following error:

```
fatal: Couldn't look up commit object for HEAD
```

Why? Is there a reason why I should be unable to delete branches from a  bare repository?

Comment: See also "[How do I delete a local git branch when it can't look up commit object in '`refs/heads`'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239742/6309)"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make sure you use a capitol `D` in the command, in this case you would type `git branch -D <branch_name>`. Note that this will only delete the branch from your local computer

If you are trying to delete a *remote* branch, type `git push origin :<branch_name>` (remember to add the colon)

Answer (score 3):

To avoid this confusion you can use

> "git push origin --delete branch_name"

this deletes remote branch not local branch.

Answer (score 1):

Find the file .git/refs/heads/branch_name in Windows Explorer and directly delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This only happens when the default branch (the branch HEAD in the bare repository folder is pointing to - usually `master`) doesn't exist locally.
If it does exist - you would be able to delete the branch with `branch -d` even from a bare repository folder (-d assuming it was merged).

If you are working with git worktrees - issuing the command from the worktree may succeed (same condition regarding HEAD of the worktree should be met)

Answer (score 0):

From [Pyrocks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3615830/pyrocks)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50623063/6309):

> This only happens when the default branch (the branch HEAD in the bare repository folder is pointing to - usually `master`) doesn't exist locally

This case is addressed with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), which fixes a bug where [`git branch -d`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/26734da056d83fe362f1c3364f273062d2cc5a5b/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L98)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--d))</sup> did not work on an orphaned HEAD.

See [commit eb20e63](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb20e63f5a96e24852c6ab1eca9f96af2648802f) (02 Nov 2022) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit 26734da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26734da056d83fe362f1c3364f273062d2cc5a5b), 18 Nov 2022)</sup>

> ### [`branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb20e63f5a96e24852c6ab1eca9f96af2648802f): gracefully handle '`-d`' on orphan HEAD
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Martin von Zweigbergk</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> When deleting a branch, "[`git branch -d`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/eb20e63f5a96e24852c6ab1eca9f96af2648802f/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L98)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--d))</sup> has a safety check that ensures the branch is merged to its upstream (if any), or to HEAD.
> To do that, naturally we try to resolve HEAD to a commit object.
> If we're on an orphan branch (i.e., HEAD points to a branch that does not yet exist), that will fail, and we'll bail with an error:
>
> ```
> $ git branch -d to-delete
> fatal: Couldn't look up commit object for HEAD
> ```
>
> This usually isn't that big of a deal.
>
> The deletion would fail anyway, since the branch isn't merged to HEAD, and you'd need to use "-D" (or "-f").

See "[How do I delete a local git branch when it can't look up commit object in 'refs/heads'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239742/6309)", since Git 2.34 (Q4 2021) added the `--force` option to `git branch -d`.

> And doing so skips the HEAD resolution, courtesy of [67affd5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67affd5173da059ca60aab7896985331acacd9b4) ("[`git-branch -D`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/67affd5173da059ca60aab7896985331acacd9b4/Documentation/git-branch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch))</sup>: make it work even when on a yet-to-be-born branch", 2006-11-24, Git v1.5.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67affd5173da059ca60aab7896985331acacd9b4)).
>
> But there are still two problems:
>
> 1. The error message isn't very helpful.
>    We should give the usual "`not fully merged`" message, which points the user at "`branch -D`".
>    That was a problem even back in [67affd5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67affd5173da059ca60aab7896985331acacd9b4).
> 2. Even without a HEAD, these days it's still possible for the deletion to succeed.
>    After [67affd5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67affd5173da059ca60aab7896985331acacd9b4), [commit 99c419c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99c419c91554e9f60940228006b7d39d42704da7) (branch -d: base the , 2009-12-29, Git v1.7.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/630724ca79b1a7893a8d9c04367eae857ff1a7b0)) (`branch -d`: base the "`already-merged`" safety on the branch it merges with, 2009-12-29) made it OK to delete a branch if it is merged to its upstream.
>
> We can fix both by removing the `die()` in `delete_branches()` completely, leaving `head_rev` `NULL` in this case.
> It's tempting to stop there, as it appears at first glance that the rest of the code does the right thing with a `NULL`.
> But sadly, it's not quite true.
>
> We end up feeding the `NULL` to `repo_is_descendant_of()`.
> In the traditional code path there, we call `repo_in_merge_bases_many()`.
> It feeds the `NULL` to `repo_parse_commit()`, which is smart enough to return an error, and we immediately return "no, it's not a descendant".