# How do I delete a local git branch when it can't look up commit object in 'refs/heads'?

Tags: git, branch

Lately every git pull I do gives me an error message like:

> error: refs/heads/TestBranch123 does not point to a valid object!

These are old branches and I don't care, so I'd just like to delete them so I don't see the error anymore. When I try to delete the branch I can't for a similar error.

> git branch -D TestBranch123
>
> error: Couldn't look up commit object for 'refs/heads/TestBranch123'

Comment: With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), a `git branch -D TestBranch123` will actually work! See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239742/6309)

Answer (score 14):

Those error messages sound worrying to me. Your repository might be corrupt. Git should not garbage collect commits that branches are pointing to. You might want to try `git fsck`, as torek suggests, to verify your repository.

However, you could delete the file representing the branch from your git repository:

```
rm .git/refs/heads/TestBranch123
```

You should also clean up any references to the branch from your git config files.

Comment: I'd recommend running `git fsck` (maybe with `--strict` too, though that's much less important).  Also, if the "bad" branch ref has been packed you may have to edit `.git/packed-refs`.

Answer (score 1):

8 years later, you won't get that error message anymore.

Adding `--force` will be enough:

```
git branch -d --force TestBranch123
# or
git branch -D TestBranch123
```

"[`git branch -D`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ec8d24f05df6966d229e2078da78ea46aea7b41c/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L103)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--D))</sup> `<branch>` used to refuse to remove a broken branch ref that points at a missing commit, which has been corrected with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021).

See [commit 597a977](https://github.com/git/git/commit/597a97748924e8ce0b829f668acc8f7a6849b05f) (27 Aug 2021) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ec8d24f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec8d24f05df6966d229e2078da78ea46aea7b41c), 08 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/597a97748924e8ce0b829f668acc8f7a6849b05f): allow deleting dangling branches with `--force`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Ulrich Windl</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> [`git branch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/597a97748924e8ce0b829f668acc8f7a6849b05f/Documentation/git-branch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch))</sup> only allows deleting branches that point to valid commits.
> Skip that check if `--force` is given, as the caller is indicating with it that they know what they are doing and accept the consequences.
> This allows deleting dangling branches, which previously had to be reset to a valid start-point using `--force` first.

`git branch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/597a97748924e8ce0b829f668acc8f7a6849b05f/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L121-L122):

> branch irrespective of its merged status, or whether it even
> points to a valid commit.