# How to delete a branch created with `arc feature`

Tags: git, git-branch

I inputted the following.

```
$ git init
$ arc feature newfolder
$ arc pull
```

Now I cannot delete the `newfolder` by using the following:

```
$ git branch -d newfolder
```

I get the following error

```
fatal: Couldn't look up newfolder object for HEAD
```

Then I tried

```
$ git branch -D newfolder

error: Cannot delete branch 'newfolder' checked out at '/home/myusername'
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I need to do this in CLI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git branch -d <BRANCH>: Fatal - Couldn't look up commit object for HEAD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651506/git-branch-d-branch-fatal-couldnt-look-up-commit-object-for-head)

Answer (score 1):

The error:

> ```
> fatal: Couldn't look up newfolder object for HEAD
> ```

seems to indicate your Git repo has been corrupted.  (This could be due to the way the `arc` command works, but I'm not familiar with it.)  Specifically, I believe that error means Git couldn't find the commit that `newfolder` points to.

If you don't care about this and just want to delete the branch, you were correct to try `git branch -D newfolder`. The next error you got is because you can't delete the branch that is currently checked out.  From [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/32142207/2747593), I see that `arc feature` creates a branch, sets the tracking branch, and checks out the branch, so that is why you have it checked out.

Instead, switch to another branch and try again:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D newfolder
```

Comment: Apologies. The error was actually `fatal: Couldn't look up commit object for HEAD`

Comment: When I try `git checkout master` I get the following `error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: What is the output of `git branch`?

Comment: @NeverPhased How about `git branch -a`?